# A weak fixed point property for Grassmannian

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f$ be  a  continuous  function on  complex  Grassmannian $G(k, 2n+1)$. Is it true to say that there is  a  $k$-plane $Y$  such that $Y$ has  nontrivial intersection with $f(Y)$?

A motivation for this  question is  the  following  alternative  proof  for  fixed point
property of  $CP^{2n}$:

Assume  that $f$ is  a  map on $CP^{2n}$ without  fixed point. Let  $l$ be  the  canonical line bundle on $CP^{2n}$. By  $f^*(l)$  we mean the  pull back bundle. Then $l$ has  trivial intersection with $f^*(l)$, since  $f$ has  no  fixed point. This implies that a complement of $l$, in the $2n+1$ trivial bundle, has a sub-bundle $f^*(l)$. This  is  a contradiction because the Chern  class of each  complement of the canonical line bundle is  $1-x+x^2-.....+x^{2n}$, which does not  have  a  rational root$.

So our  main  question has  affirmative answer if  the  answer to the  following question 
is  affirmative:

> Is it true to say a that a complement of canonical $k$ plane bundle on $G(K, 2N+1)$ in the trivial $2n+1$ bundle does not have a $k$-dimensional sub-bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As proved by Bob Stong [Robert E. Stong, Splitting the universal bundles over Grassmannians, Algebraic and Differential Topology - Global Differential Geometry, Occas. 90th Anniv. M. Morse’s Birth, Teubner-Texte Math. 70, 275-287 (1984)], over the complex Grassmann manifolds, the canonical bundles never contain proper real or complex subbundles.

Best regards,
                    Július Korbaš

Comment: thank you but this is  not  my  question. My  question was the  following:

Comment: My  question was the following:Let E  be  a complement  to the canonical k plane bundle is  it true to say that E has  no k dimensional  sub bundle

Comment: Dear Ali Taghavi, You just need to understand that by the canonical (also called universal) bundles Bob Stong meant both the k-plane bundle and its complementary bundle. Best regards, Július Korbaš

Comment: Thank you very  much  for your  answer  and  your  reference to Stong  paper.

Comment: Dear  Julius Korbas, in the  Stong  paper, is there a restriction on k and n, when he state his result oabout G(k,n)? If there is  no restriction, it seems  that  some  thing is  missing. Because  a  similar argument  as  above  proof  of  fixed point property of even dimensional projective space, can  be  repeated to  give  a  proof  for  fixed point  property for odd dimensional projective space. But it is  well known that CP^n  has  no  FPP  when  n is  odd